# Find Graph Laplacian Matrix Kth smallest eigenpair

Tags: algorithm, graph, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement Spectral Graph partitioning, but I am stuck on how to do it. The basic idea is to find the second smallest eigenvalue and its vector (fiedler vector), if you want to bisect the graph. If the graph is partitioned to any arbitrary number of parts, fiedler vector can still be used, or we can use the smallest Kth eigenpair, I am intending to compare the results.

I found the power iteration method seems to be useful, but I am confused about it, first the initial vector selection seems random, in case of connected graph the smallest eigenpair is known, so I am asking do I need to run the reverse power iteration, (k-1) times to find the Kth smallest eigenpair?

I am open to suggestions, and corrections.

Comment: I am also interested in doing something similar so if you found any solution please post it.